# Unit test fail when try run asset equals of array in Matomo

Tags: php, phpunit, matomo, piwiktracker

Perhaps need to enable a PHP extension to do this works. All tests with `assertEquals` are falling when using `usort` in array's.

Take a look below in the result of a falling test:

```
13) Piwik\Tests\Unit\DataAccess\JoinGeneratorTest::test_sortTablesForJoin_shouldSortTablesWithCustomJoinRequiringEachOther2
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
Array (
    0 => 'log_link_visit_action'
    1 => Array (
        'table' => 'log_action'
-        'tableAlias' => 'log_action_idaction_event_action'
-        'joinOn' => 'log_link_visit_action.idaction_event_action = log_action_idaction_event_action.idaction'
+        'tableAlias' => 'log_action_visit_entry_idaction_name'
+        'joinOn' => 'log_visit.visit_entry_idaction_name = log_action_visit_entry_idaction_name.idaction'
    )
    2 => Array (
        'table' => 'log_action'
-        'tableAlias' => 'log_action_visit_entry_idaction_name'
-        'joinOn' => 'log_visit.visit_entry_idaction_name = log_action_visit_entry_idaction_name.idaction'
+        'tableAlias' => 'log_action_idaction_event_action'
+        'joinOn' => 'log_link_visit_action.idaction_event_action = log_action_idaction_event_action.idaction'
    )
)

/matomo-3.5.1/tests/PHPUnit/Unit/DataAccess/LogQueryBuilder/JoinGeneratorTest.php:428

FAILURES!
Tests: 6521, Assertions: 10544, Failures: 13.
```

Comment: The version of PHP is 7.2.20. When I change PHP to version 5.6.37, this test pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order must be identical on arrays for `assertEquals` and `assertSame` to pass. Imagine if you json_encode both whether or not they will end up with the same result. Looks like your arrays are not in the same sort order based on the phpunit output.

```
<?php

class ArrayTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    // Fails
    public function testArraysEqualsDifferentOrder() {
        $a = Array(['3', '2'], '1');
        $b = Array(['2', '3'], '1');

        $this->assertEquals($a, $b);
    }

    // Fails
    public function testArraysSameDifferentOrder() {
        $a = Array(['3', '2'], '1');
        $b = Array(['2', '3'], '1');

        $this->assertSame($a, $b);
    }

    // Passes
    public function testArraysEqualSameOrder() {
        $a = Array(['2', '3'], '1');
        $b = Array(['2', '3'], '1');

        $this->assertEquals($a, $b);
    }

    // Passes
    public function testArraysSameSameOrder() {
        $a = Array(['2', '3'], '1');
        $b = Array(['2', '3'], '1');

        $this->assertSame($a, $b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try `assertSame` for arrays that is much beter